# Merge HTML Element object with a custom object

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out why I can't merge 2 or more objects when one of them is an HTML Element.

**EDIT**:
Why when i merged with `Object.assign` 2 "normal" objects like `obj1` and `obj2` i get the values from obj2 on common properties, but when i do the same with `root` which is an HTML element i don't get its values (for example the value of `id` property)

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const obj1 = { id: "obj1", textContent: "i am obj1" };
const obj2 = { id: "obj2", textContent: "i am obj2"};
const merged1 = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2); // the new object got the id and textContent from obj2
const merged2 = Object.assign({}, obj1, root); // the new object got the id and textContent from obj1. why not from root?
console.log(merged1);
console.log(merged2);
console.log(root.id);
console.log(root.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="root">i am root</div>
```

Comment: Are you expecting `"i am obj1"` and `"i am obj2"` to be concatenated?

Comment: nope, i am expecting to get a new object while the `id` and `textContent` properties will get their values from the `root` object as its the last argument passed to `Object.assign`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `root` as first parameter to `Object.assign()`

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const obj1 = { id: "obj1", textContent: "i am obj1" };
const obj2 = { textContent: "i am obj2"}
const merged = Object.assign(root, obj1, obj2);
console.log(merged);
console.log(root.id);
console.log(root.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="root">i am root</div>
```

> i don't want to override `root`, i want a new object and get the
>   relevant values from the `root` object.

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const obj1 = { id: "obj1", textContent: "i am obj1" };
const obj2 = { textContent: "i am obj2"};
const {id, textContent} = root;
const merged = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2, {id, textContent});
console.log(merged);
console.log(root.id);
console.log(root.textContent);
```

```html
<div id="root">i am root</div>
```

> EDIT: Why when i merged with `Object.assign` 2 "normal" objects like
>   `obj1` and `obj2` i get the values from obj2 on common properties, but
>   when i do the same with `root` which is an HTML element i don't get its
>   values (for example the value of `id` property)

`Object.assign()` can copy enumerable properties of an object. `HTMLDivElement` `id` and `textContent` properties are not enumerable.

[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object. It will return the target object.

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const props = ["textContent", "id"];

for (const prop of props) console.log(Object.propertyIsEnumerable(root, prop));
```

```html
<div id="root">i am root</div>
```

Comment: i don't want to mutate `root`, i want a new object and get the relevant values from the `root` object.

Comment: thank you, i know i can do that but that's not my point (what if i have like 20 attributes?). my question is why is it different from "normal" objects why can't i use `Object.assign` on an html element?

Comment: @Sag1v Not sure what you mean? Can you provide an example of expected result at a  "normal object"?