# Is (Document) an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

In this code :

```
document.getElementById()
```

Is `document` an object that has properties and methods?

If yes, is `getElementById()` a method on this object?

If no, What are `document` and `getElementById` considered?

Comment: What are you trying to determine?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `document` is an object.

```
typeof document; // "object"
```

And `getElementById` is a property on that object.

Comment: `getElementById` is an method of the `Document` prototype.

Comment: Yes, it is inherited via the prototype chain.

Comment: `!!document.getElementById` ==> `true`

Comment: @Kaiido `'getElementById' in document === true` The function is still accessible from `document`, despite not being the direct owner.

Comment: hmm.. *"property **on**"* not **of** you're right.. somehow misleading though.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Not certain if OP is trying to check if `"getElementById"` is enumerable `Object.propertyIsEnumerable(document, "getElementById")`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348923/merge-html-element-object-with-a-custom-object/44348960#44348960

Comment: @Kaiido `Document` is a function, not the same as `document`, no? `typeof Document; typeof document`

Comment: @guest271314 `document` inherits from `Document` through `[currentDocumentType]Document` proto. So depending on what are the expectations of OP, it may do an difference.

Comment: @Trott You are not very good in OOP.... It is method for sure but not property. `typeof document.getElementById
"function"`

Comment: Document should be the prototype, consider it as the Class definition and document is a instance of Document

Comment: @aokaddaoc It's a property whose values happen to be a function. Saying that makes it "not [a] property" is a misunderstanding of JavaScript.

Comment: @Trott https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Well `A JavaScript method is a property containing a function definition.`. So yeah it is a property but method is more precise.

Answer (score 0):

In browser, `document` is a instance of `Document`.
`document instanceof Document` =>`true`.

It represents the whole HTML page.
And `document` is a property of `window`.
`window.document === document` => `true`.

So it can used as global object.